# Upgrade but console still displays old version

Tags: node.js, upgrade

I want to upgrade my `node` from current version (7.2.1) to the latest (8.5) on my Ubuntu server.

I follow the instruction [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/), in `Debian and Ubuntu based Linux distributions` section, by running 2 commands below:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

After installing, I check the version by: `node -v`, but the console still prints `7.2.1`. Why is that?

I have some Node program running on `Node 7.2.1`. After upgrading to `Node 8.5`, will there by any conflicts? Should I rerun them?

Regards

EDIT: Add an example to make sure the nodejs still stays obsolete.

The major difference between node `7.x` and node `8.x` is `async/await`. So, I just write this simple example to check if node "understands" the new syntax:

```
getABC()

async function getABC() {
  const a = await getA()

  console.log("result: " + a)
}

function getA() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    return 5
  }, 100)
}
```

Result:

```
result: undefined
```

So, node on my server is not updated yet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apt-get is bugged when it comes to installing nodejs, use the following to install with nvm

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.4/install.sh | bash

nvm install 8.5.0

nvm use 8.5.0

//check with 
node -v
```